# Heroku deployment Gemfile syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

this is my Gemfile code. For some reason it has a syntax error that I can't figure. Can someone please help?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
   gem 'pg'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: The syntax seems correct. Please post the full Heroku error log.

Comment: when i run bundle install, the terminal just shouts "Gemfile syntax error:". The error seems to be coming from the last two groups.

Comment: Are you running the latest bundler?

Comment: Just ran "gem install bundler" and tried bundle installing again but it gives me the same error. Actually, now running bundle install at all even after removing the groups gives me the same error.

Comment: Removing the production and test groups, and adding "gem 'sqlite3'" instead fixes the error. but then how do I add the gem for pg? :(

Comment: Post the exact error so we know what we are dealing with

Comment: what  the local bundler says about the **Gemfile**?

Comment: the exact error is: Gemfile syntax error.